# What is the difference between these two Active Bandpass filter circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter, band-pass

[image]

[image]

Both are bandpass filters. The circuit in figure 1 is easy to understand and I can calculate the gain and cutoff frequency without any problem.

Regarding the configuration in figure 2, I would like to know what is the point of cascading two bandpass filters? Furthermore, how do I calculate the lower and upper cutoff frequencies? Why would anyone prefer the circuit in figure 2 over the circuit in figure 1?

Thank you :)

Comment: Neither block of the second circuit is a bandpass. Investigate the frequency response for very large frequencies....

Answer (score 1):

The engineering way to design bandpass filters is to start by deciding

- the wanted passband and the maximum allowed attenuation at frequencies in the passband
- maximum allowed gain variation in the passband
- the wanted stopband and the minimum wanted attenuation at the stopband
- possible other requirements that the planned application states, for ex. phase linearity, stopband attenuation curve steepness dB/octave, available technology, tolerances etc...

The only engineering reason to prefer version 2 is that it makes possible fulfill the requirements that are based on the planned application. Version 2 can have 12 dB/octave steepness of the stopband attenuation curve, version 1 has only 6dB/octave.

Not asked:

None of these filters have any resonances like for ex. passive LC filters can have. Your filters have very mild attenuation slopes between passpand and stopband.  Much more effective frequency range selection is possible with LC filters and also with active RC filters which apply resonances. Filter design math doesn't talk about resonances, there the term is "complex transfer function poles"

The easiest way to find the frequency response of your filters when the component values are known, is to make AC analysis in a circuit analyzer. Several of them are available online. Even this site has a well working analyzer (=Circuit Lab). It's free for us, but it has only a limited selection of transistors, opamps, diodes etc. semiconductor components. It's the Schematic Editor in the answering dialog.

Electronics engineering textbooks have formulas for the frequency responses of your presented circuits. Finding 3dB limits need understanding the math used in the book.